# Geography/Location dimension table for datawarehousing

Tags: gis, analytics, data-warehouse, dimensions

Is there a place I can view or download the geography dimension for data warehousing purposes?  if not how do I go about creating one?

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide more details of what you are trying to model specifically? Typically capturing the latitude and longitude in the data warehouse is sufficient and then relying on your presentation tool (BI or Mapping) to address the details of distance or map generation. Some DBMS' provide better native support for geographic details such as calculating distance between two points and latitude /longitude as data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

purchased data from  - http://www.zipcodedownload.com/